# I have a unity project where i work with colors but i need some help at it

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I try to make a game where you fly and through the gates and try to match the color of the gate and your color.But i need some help at matching the colors becouse u see i have like 3 gates and i made that them could get a random color but how to i do that when i ,,colide'' or intersect with the gate to compare the colors.like if colors match you can continue if not then gameover.
here are my scripts.
 My code on Player:
[image]

```
public void ColorChange()
{
   int colors = Random.Range(0, color.Length);

   material.color = color[colors];

    myColor = color[colors];
}
```

My code on Triple Gate:

```
public void ColorChange()
{


    int color1 = Random.Range(0, color.Length);
    int color2 = Random.Range(0, color.Length);
    int color3 = Random.Range(0, color.Length);

    material[0].color = color[color1];
    material[1].color = color[color2];
    material[2].color = color[color3];
}
```

Comment: Where is your attempt at writing the `OnCollisionEnter` code? And where is the problem?

Comment: @UnholySheep You mean OnTriggerEnter, a bit misleading hinting at a wrong solution.

Comment: @dowhilefor I disagree, since OPs question is IMO not specific enough to determine whether they want colliders or triggers. Even so, if they look up colliders and triggers in the official documentation they should be able to determine on their own which one is better suited for their needs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Gates and Ship first need to be physics objects. At the minimum you need to add [RigidBody](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.html) and proper *Bounding Volumes* or **Colliders** to them, (For the gates a [BoxCollider](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/BoxCollider.html) for example). Your Gates also should be [Triggers](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider-isTrigger.html), otherwise the Ship would not be allowed to enter the Gate and instead crash against it.

Now the interesting part: The Gate should have an `OnTriggerEnter` method were we can test the two colors. The issue is, you can't compare colors directly (no equality operator on colors) and in fact you shouldn't. One solution is to compare each individual component of the color with each other utilizing a small margin of error, please note that this [isn't ideal either](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider-isTrigger.html) but should be fine for a game.

```
class ColorGate : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Color gateColor;

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        var playerShip = other.gameObject as PlayerShip;

        var c1 = playerShip.currentColor;
        var c2 = gateColor;

        if(Math.Abs(c1.r - c2.r) < 0.01f && 
           Math.Abs(c1.g - c2.g) < 0.01f && 
           Math.Abs(c1.b - c2.b) < 0.01f 
           /*&& Math.Abs(c1.a - c2.a) < 0.01f only if you really need it*/ )
        {
            // colors match!
        }
        else
        {
            // colors don't match
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well in a final way i managed to do it.I added triggers to every gate and for exemple if i trigger gate 2 then the script will check if player's color matched the material number 2 becouse it's gate number 2.Anyway thank you very much  for helping,i apreciate very much!

Comment: Remember to mark an answer as helpful once you are done with the question.